# WPF mvvm property in viewmodel without setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm dealing with some WPF problems using and sticking to the MVVM pattern.

Most of my properties look like this:

```
public string Period
{
    get { return _primaryModel.Period; }
    set
    {
        if (_primaryModel.Period != value)
        {
            _primaryModel.Period = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Period");
        }
    }
}
```

This works excellent.

However I also have some properties like this:

```
public bool EnableConsignor
{
    get
    {
        return (ConsignorViewModel.Id != 0);
    }
}
```

It doesn't have a setter as the id is changed "automatically" (every time the save of `ConsignorViewModel` is called. However this leads to the problem that the "system" doesn't know when the bool changes from false to true (as no `RaisePropertyChanged` is called).

Answer (score 7):

For these kinds of properties, you need to just raise `PropertyChanged` when the dependent data is changed. Something like:

```
public object ConsignorViewModel
{
   get { return consignorViewModel; }
   set
   {
       consignorViewModel = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("ConsignorViewModel");
       RaisePropertyChanged("EnableConsignor");
   } 
}
```

`RaisePropertyChanged` can be invoked in any method, so just put it after whatever operation that would change the return value of `EnableConsignor` is performed. The above was just an example.

Comment: And, yes, everybody feels dirty when they do this.

Comment: It's not that dirty, and preferred practice from Microsoft team so far (pre C# 6.0). It's bit difficult when it comes to refactoring. With C# 6.0 one can use `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EnableConsignor))` instead, which is refactoring safe. If you can't use C# 6.0 and don't have performance critical code, there is still a custom implementation of RaisePropertyChanged which takes an Expression and use it to obtain the property name as string

Comment: @Tseng Knowing that its not dirty doesn't change me *feeling* dirty every time I do it ;)

Comment: Yea, but no alternative for performance if there is a high number of bindings which get updated very fast. But Visual Studio 2015 RTM is close, luckily :P

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this a while ago an it has been working great

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
public class CalculatedProperty : Attribute
{
    private string[] _props;
    public CalculatedProperty(params string[] props)
    {
        this._props = props;
    }

    public string[] Properties
    {
        get
        {
            return _props;
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel base

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>> calculatedPropertiesOfTypes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>>();

    private readonly bool hasComputedProperties;
    public ObservableObject()
    {
        Type t = GetType();
        if (!calculatedPropertiesOfTypes.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
        {
            var props = t.GetProperties();

            foreach (var pInfo in props)
            {
                var attr = pInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CalculatedProperty>(false);
                if (attr == null)
                    continue;

                if (!calculatedPropertiesOfTypes.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
                {
                    calculatedPropertiesOfTypes[t.FullName] = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
                }
                calculatedPropertiesOfTypes[t.FullName][pInfo.Name] = attr.Properties;
            }
        }

        if (calculatedPropertiesOfTypes.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
            hasComputedProperties = true;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        if (this.hasComputedProperties)
        {
            //check for any computed properties that depend on this property
            var computedPropNames =
                calculatedPropertiesOfTypes[this.GetType().FullName]
                .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(propertyName))
                .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);

            if (computedPropNames != null)
                if (!computedPropNames.Any())
                    return;

            //raise property changed for every computed property that is dependant on the property we did just set
            foreach (var computedPropName in computedPropNames)
            {
                //to avoid stackoverflow as a result of infinite recursion if a property depends on itself!
                if (computedPropName == propertyName)
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("A property can't depend on itself");

                OnPropertyChanged(computedPropName);
            }
        }
    }


    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int _x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { SetField(ref _x, value); }
    }

    private int _y;

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { SetField(ref _y, value); }

    }

    //use the CalculatedProperty annotation for properties that depend on other properties and pass it the prop names that it depends on
    [CalculatedProperty("X", "Y")]
    public int Z
    {
        get { return X * Y; }
    }

    [CalculatedProperty("Z")]
    public int M
    {
        get { return Y * Z; }
    }

}
```

Note that:

- it uses reflection only once per type
- `SetField` sets the field and raises property changed if there is a new value
- you don't need to pass property name to `SetField` as long as you call it within a setter because the
  `[CallerMemberName]` does it for you since c# 5.0.
- if you call `SetField` outside the setter then you will have to pass
  it the property name
- as per my last update you can avoid using `SetField` by setting the field directly and then
  calling OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName") and it will raise
  PropertyChanged for all properties that are
  dependant on it.
- in c# 6 you can use the nameof operator to get the property name such
  as `nameof(Property)`
- `OnPropertyChanged` will call itself recusively if there are computed
  properties

XAML for testing

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding X,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Y,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Z,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding M,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This looks like a very clean approach I'd like to use. However the `SetField` method doesn't allow properties to be passed. How can this be done?

Comment: @mosquito87 improved it a little bit, now calling OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName") will raise property changed for all dependant properties unlike before where only calling SetField did so, test the above example with the xaml i provided

Comment: that's a interesting thing, but this line doesn't compile : `pInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CalculatedProperty>(false)`. May be you want to use `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)` ?

Comment: @Xaruth i am using .Net 4.5 you are probably using 4.0, if so use the overload you suggested with .First

Comment: @Xaruth FirstOrDefault!

Comment: @decoherence yes, that's it, I'm using 4.0. I already think of `FirstOfDefault` and modify `(attr as CalculatedProperty).Properties`. I will test it right now

Comment: @Xaruth exactly  also  remove `[CallerMemberName]` and pass the property name to `SetField(ref _x,value,"X")`

Comment: `[CallerMemberName]`is not a problem, I use it in 4.0 tanks to Thomas Levesque : http://www.thomaslevesque.fr/2012/06/