# Update multiple properties on event raised

Tags: c#, .net, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to understand how to trigger all the properties update when new data available.

For example I have two properties:

```
    public string PropertyOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyOne
        }
        set
        {
            _propertyOne= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string PropertyTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            _propertyTwo = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

When I receive notification about new data I assign my properties:

```
Mediator<ViewModelMessages>.Instance.Register(ViewModelMessages.OnNewData, this.OnNewData);

private void OnNewData(object obj)
{
      PropertyOne = (MyClass)obj.propertyOne;
      PropertyTwo = (MyClass)obj.propertyTwo;
}
```

What I want to have is something like this:

```
private MyClass _myClass;

private void OnNewData(object obj)
{
     _myClass = (MyClass)obj;
}

public string PropertyOne
{
    get
    {
         return _myClass.PropertyOne;
    }
    set
    {
         _myClass.PropertyOne = value;
         this.OnPropertyChanged();
 }
    }

 public string PropertyTwo
 {
     get
     {
         return _myClass.propertyTwo;
     }
     set
     {
         _myClass.propertyTwo = value;
         this.OnPropertyChanged();
     }
  }
```

So when new data arrived, my properties are automatically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by passing an Empty string or null to your OnPropertyChanged rather than a property name, but note that property changed will get raised for all properties in this case.

Comment: Empty string? Why? FYI, I am using ReSharper's annotations that will pick up the name of my property.

Comment: @inside thats how it works you pass it an empty string and it will raise property changed for all properties, i don't know what resharper is

Comment: @inside https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx its mentioned in the docs

Comment: @inside this answer might be helpful to you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524907/wpf-mvvm-property-in-viewmodel-without-setter/29535537#29535537 if your properties are read only and depend on other props

Comment: thank you, OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty) did the job!